# PHP session is not setting and data not saving in mysql database after password_compat success but works with md5()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

When I use `password_verify` and after success my sessions will not set, but will `echo` a variable after success and redirect me to  the home page. The page is not giving me any errors when i refresh the page it will allow me to login again. I build it with `md5()` and sessions gets set after `md5() verification`. Is there any error i am missing ? I do have `session_start` in my `check_login_status.php` file.

**javascript**

```
function login(){
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p = _("password").value;
    if(e == "" || p == ""){
        _("status").innerHTML = "You have to fill out everything buddy...";
    } else {
        _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("status").innerHTML = '<div class="preloader-wrapper small right active"><div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue"><div class="circle-clipper left"><div class="circle"></div></div><div class="gap-patch"><div class="circle"></div></div><div class="circle-clipper right"><div class="circle"></div></div></div><div class="spinner-layer spinner-red"><div class="circle-clipper left"><div class="circle"></div></div><div class="gap-patch"><div class="circle"></div></div><div class="circle-clipper right"><div class="circle"></div></div></div><div class="spinner-layer spinner-yellow"><div class="circle-clipper left"><div class="circle"></div></div><div class="gap-patch"><div class="circle"></div></div><div class="circle-clipper right"><div class="circle"></div></div></div><div class="spinner-layer spinner-green"><div class="circle-clipper left"><div class="circle"></div></div><div class="gap-patch"><div class="circle"></div></div><div class="circle-clipper right"><div class="circle"></div></div></div></div>';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                    _("status").innerHTML = "Login unsuccessful, please go back and try again buddy.";
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.location = "@"+ajax.responseText;
                    // above sends user to user page after login
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
    }
}
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
include_once("php_includes/password.php");

// If user is already logged in, header that weenis away
if($user_ok == true){
    header("location: home.php?u=".$_SESSION["username"]);
    exit();
}
?><?php
// AJAX CALLS THIS LOGIN CODE TO EXECUTE
if(isset($_POST["e"])){
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES AND SANITIZE
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p =  $_POST['p'];
    //$pw = password_hash($p, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $pw = $p;
    // GET USER IP ADDRESS
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    $online="online";
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($e == "" || $p == ""){
        echo "login_failed";
        exit();
    } else {
    // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' OR username='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];

        if (password_verify($pw, $db_pass_str)){
            // CREATE THEIR SESSIONS AND COOKIES
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $db_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $db_pass_str;
            setcookie("id", $db_id, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
            setcookie("pass", $db_pass_str, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE); 
            // UPDATE THEIR "IP" AND "LASTLOGIN" FIELDS
            $online = "online";
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET status='$online', SET ip='$ip', lastlogin=now() WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            echo $db_username;
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "login_failed";
            exit();
        }
    }
    exit();
}
?>
<form class="col s12" id="loginform" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s8">
          <i class="mdi-action-account-circle prefix"></i>
          <input type="text" id="email" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="88"  class="validate">
          <label for="icon_prefix">Username or Email</label>
        </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s8">
          <i class="mdi-editor-mode-edit prefix"></i>
          <input type="password" id="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="255" class="validate">
          <label for="icon_telephone">Password</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <button class="btn blue waves-effect waves-light right" id="loginbtn" onclick="login()" type="submit" >Login </button>

      <div id="status"></div>

      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the password from the database was created with `password_hash()` and not by your old `md5` hashing routine?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes password created with $p_hash = password_hash($p, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

Comment: @riggsfolly I got the session variables to set,  now only the cookies will not set